# How to check if the first half of a word is the same as the second half, within a list?

Tags: python

How can I check if the first half of a word is the same as the second half within a list of words and determine the number of words whose halves are the same within the list?

For example, given the list:

```py
["abcabc","abcccc","cbccbc","cccbbb"]
```

I want to output:

```py
["abcabc", "cbccbc"]
```

Comment: We're not going to write your code for you - can you show us what you've tried (as a [mre]) along with an explanation of where *specifically* in that attempt you're getting stuck? See also: [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension with string slicing to check that the string is of even length and that the two halves of the string are equal:

```py
data = ["abcabc","abcccc","cbccbc","cccbbb"]

[item for item in data if item[:len(item)//2] == item[len(item)//2:]]
```

This outputs:

```py
['abcabc', 'cbccbc']
```